# building the library `async-graphql-extension-apollo-tracing` fails due to `protoc` not found

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, protoc, async-graphql, apollo-studio

I am trying to build a project which uses [async-graphql-extension-apollo-tracing](https://crates.io/crates/async-graphql-extension-apollo-tracing) but it fails with the following error

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `async-graphql-extension-apollo-tracing v3.2.14`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/target/release/build/async-graphql-extension-apollo-tracing-717675847b3f881b/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/agents.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/reports.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=.

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/prost-build-0.12.3/src/lib.rs:1521:10:
  Could not find `protoc` installation and this build crate cannot proceed without
      this knowledge. If `protoc` is installed and this crate had trouble finding
      it, you can set the `PROTOC` environment variable with the specific path to your
      installed `protoc` binary.If you're on debian, try `apt-get install protobuf-compiler` or download it from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

  For more information: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc

  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Error: Process completed with exit code 123.
```

Even though I have installed `protoc` using [arduino/setup-protoc](https://github.com/arduino/setup-protoc).

More information about the build is present here https://github.com/tailcallhq/tailcall/actions/runs/8242720704/job/22542201296

I tried updating the version of setup-protoc to latest version but the problem still persists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDvhc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.